# Using nested queries and many to many relationships in Doctrine's QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I'm having a bit of trouble thinking of how to approach this using a query builder. Currently, I have three objects that are the following:

```
HelpRequest
    id
    ...
    status

Filter
    id
    name
    statuses ->  ManyToMany(targetEntity="Status")

Status
    id
    name
```

A filter can have multiple statuses so there is a table that is keeping track what statuses are part of a specific filter.

Sample Data

```
help_requests
---
| id | content | status |
| 1  | hello   | 3      |

filters
---
| id | name     |
| 1  | Active   |
| 1  | Inactive |

statuses
---
| id | name                  |
| 1  | Open                  |
| 2  | Closed                |
| 3  | Waiting User Response |

status_filter
---
| status_id | filter_id |
| 1         | 1         |
| 3         | 1         |
| 2         | 2         |
```

The `status_filter` table is automatically generated from a ManyToMany relationship in doctrine between a Status object and a Filter object.

Based on the given information, I've written this SQL query but now I'm having troubles writing this with QueryBuilder.

```
SELECT * FROM help_requests WHERE status IN (SELECT status_id FROM status_filter WHERE filter_id = 1)
```

If there's any more information I can give, let me know. I've read multiple questions on SO and have tried a number of things but I can't seem to get it right. I'm aware I could just hard coded that query but I'd like the experience using QueryBuilder

Thanks for the help!

**Update**

In the end, since I couldn't get it to work with QueryBuilder and I didn't want to create a new entity solely to map two other entities together, I decided to use createQuery() instead and this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
    hr
FROM
    HelpRequest hr
WHERE
    hr.status
IN (
    SELECT
        s.id
    FROM
        Filter f
    JOIN
        f.statuses s
    WHERE
        f.name = :name
    )
```

Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query, and put is in your HelpRequestsRepository class:

```
$subquery = $this->->select('st.status_id')
    ->from('/path/to/StatusFilter', 'st')
    ->where('st.filter_id = 1');

$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('hr')
    ->select('*')
    ->where('hr.status IN (' . $subquery->getDQL() . ')')
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity, I've edited my question. I don't have a StatusFilter object, it's simply a ManyToMany relationship between the two objects (Status and Filter). If there's a way to avoid creating an object simply to keep the two tables related, that would be great.

Comment: No matter if status_filter table is automatically generated from a ManyToMany relationship. You can create a repository class for it and query it.

Comment: Would generating a repository class for it require there to be an entity?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach in the `HelpRequestsRepository` class:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('hr');
    $qb->select("hr");
    $qb->join("::Status","s",Expr\Join::INNER_JOIN, "hr.status=s" );
    $qb->join("::Filter","f",Expr\Join::INNER_JOIN, "s.filters=f" );
    $qb->where("f.name = :name");
    $qb->setParameter('name', $nameOfTheFilterToBeFound)
```

Hope this help

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I had to step away from this problem. With your solution, I keep getting this: "Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected." Any ideas so to what I'm missing?